# Why does a Typescript variable not correctly infer its type when a typeguard and Exclude are combined?

Tags: typescript

I have this code snippet but the `return arg` line has a compile error

```
type Foo<T> = T | Error

type Successful<A> = Exclude<A, Error>

const fn = <S>(arg: Foo<S>): Successful<Foo<S>> => {
    if (arg instanceof Error) {
        throw new Error()
    }
    return arg
}
```

`Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<S, Error>'.(2322)`

Why can't the compiler understand `arg` should be type `S` only after guarding to narrow the type?

Demonstration [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxWVAPlAUQCci4iAoc0SKAZQFcBjRiAZ1YDN6AbRAQXRYCAD0bd6AEwj8ANIRJlUlRnAB2rYFA6rMURLVQAKAIZEA5gC5YCfagCUVhszaceieEgOD0Ab3JQAqABLDigTc2D1YGNVFjhQ4lIiOyg-QPSoYAALUgB3KFUIfMSyQzt-QIBfCoCiCGB6Ih1TM3JKoA)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compiler cant understand that arg should be successful type after condition. It would be great if TS understand automatically.  But this is the specifics of his work

Use type assertion

```
type Foo<T> = T | Error

type Successful<A> = Exclude<A, Error>

const fn = <S>(arg: Foo<S>): Successful<Foo<S>> => {
    if (arg instanceof Error) {
        throw new Error()
    }
    return arg as Successful<Foo<S>>
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid asserting